# Wanted to show Stacklabel on top of every grouped bar highstock while having scrollbar

Tags: highcharts

this is happening some bars are not shown stacklabel.

I also tried crop:false,but then it shows problem like all stacklabels are shown even if bars are invisible.

[stack label not shown issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aCnB.png)

[while scrolling and setting crop:true label show issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqQk8.png)

Comment: add the exact test/code in your question. Use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [the code-snippet here in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/12511801) for create a [mcve].

Comment: yAxis: {
        reversedStacks: false,
        stackLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          allowOverlap: true,
          overflow: 'allow',
          // crop: false
      },
}

I used stack labes like this. but for some bars the stack lables are not visible,so i tried crop property but it dosen't work as expected bcz i have scroll bar so the labels for hidden series are shown before scrolling.

Comment: Hi @jayanti khutwad, Please try to enable `allowOverlap` option. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.allowOverlap

Comment: hi @ppotaczek after setting allow overlap to true  it is not working in grouped bar chart   some of the stacklabels of the bars are visible alreadt which is hidden bcz of scroll  ` stackLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          allowOverlap: true,
          overflow: 'allow',
          crop: false,`

Comment: after enabling allowOverlap
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpjZ5.png

@ppotaczek plz have a look the screenshot

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek for your help,
after removing all other properties  and using just overflow:"allow" solve my problem